# How to DECRYPT in mysql with query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, encryption, phpmyadmin

I never use mysql and phpmyadmin and now i have a problem with decrypt. I need a crypting password, in the process of registration and decrypt in the login.
I only need my key for decrypt (hindsight I opted for sha1).

This work:

```
INSERT INTO user (ability,username,password) VALUES("Y","userx", AES_ENCRYPT('userx','key1234'));
```

Now i to decrypt? I test with AES_DECRYPT but return alway in Hexadecimal,also with cast but don't work.
Can someone help me by writing me the query?

Nothing I would like to do a challenging project but I would like to use these mysql methods. I just need to understand how the query works, then I adapt it to my needs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Encryption is not the way to go. Use hashes, which can't be reversed. Since you've tagged PHPMyAdmin I assume that you're using PHP. If so, you can use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` in PHP to create a hash to store in your database, and verify it after retrieval.